# HTML: when pages are saved have images / files not saved

Tags: html, reference, hyperlink

well i am not trying to apply fool proof security or anything.. all i want to know when you page a save from the web... the links `CSS` \ `JS` files and the images are not save...

HOW TO ACHIEVE IT..

again not applying any security or anything.. i know all the images will be there in temp, or you can open source and get the link to CSS Files.. just want to learn this

Comment: most browsers have options like "HTML only" and "complete page". the latter should give you everything the page contains, usually in a folder named the same as the page but without the .html extension. Firefox works this way on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: please... i know there is such an option i am a stupid developer... there is some thing like referenced links or something like that.. if you have given the path to your images, CSS files, JS files and all the other files `like that` then when the page is saved those CSS files and those images etc won't be there.. how to do it

Comment: wait a minute lemme give you an online example

Comment: http://bcproducties.com/vCard/Light/... go try saving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, CSS can be imported via `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">`, and similar goes to javascript. Further more, you can inject javascript from somewhere - I doubt that web browsers would 'know' how to save that. 
Same goes with images - If you inject them via JS, browser will be unable to save them.

As you said,it's not foolproof :)

Comment: when you do this.. save the page like file > Save > *... and you open it the CSS will be attached & working... go try to save this page and then open it to see what i mean http://bcproducties.com/vCard/Light/

Comment: the solution is `@import myCSS.css`